# whois doesn't work in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, whois, whois-ruby

I install `whois` using `$ gem install whois` and follow [Ruby Whois](http://www.ruby-whois.org/)
but when I test it in irb, it gives error:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > c = Whois::Client.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Whois
from (irb):1
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>
```

**EDIT**

when I `require 'whois'` gives another error:

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > require 'whois'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- whois
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from (irb):3
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/darshana/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks.

Comment: you should require 'whois' first

Comment: @railscard : I did that but it gives error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- whois`

Comment: can you find whois gem with "gem search whois"?

Comment: Add gem 'whois' to your project gemfile and then try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install and load the whois library .. that worked for me.

```
> gem install whois
> irb
* require 'whois'  
* c = Whois::Client.new
>>  #<Whois::Client:0x8f0fa34 @timeout=10, @settings={}>
```

Comment: I did that and gives me error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- whois`

Comment: Have you installed the whois gem?

Comment: yes. `darshana@darshana-pc:~/rails_projects/whois_test$ gem search whois *** LOCAL GEMS *** whois (2.6.4)`

Comment: I think you are using the rails console not the irb console.  Try to add the whois gem in your gemfile  ( gem 'whois' )  run bundle  then run the rails console and execute require 'whois' again

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes gems cant be required by default, for this time we need to require this gem.

For example(in your case), you added whois gem in Gemfile, then open console give following line

```
require "whois"
```

then use Whois constant should be available.

Comment: I did that and gives me error `LoadError: cannot load such file -- whois`

Comment: I think your installed gem is not included in your directory path, just go inside the gem find the whois.rb file. Then open irb give require "./whois".

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your gemfile than load the irb with `bundle exec rails c`